# Cannot implicity Convert Type WebApplication1.Add.ClassName[] to int []

Tags: c#

This is the code I want to save the AllRecords or Notes in an array but I have make another class and declare property of columns here is the code

```
public class ClassName
{
    //public int Col1 { get; set; }
    public int Col2 { get; set; }
}

public static void countCurrency(int amount)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-8QL52AL\\ASADI; Database=atm;  Integrated Security=True;");

    ClassName[] allRecords = null;
    string sql = @"SELECT id,notes
       FROM  notes";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var notes = new List<ClassName>();
            while (reader.Read())
                notes.Add(new ClassName { Col2 = reader.GetInt32(1) });
            allRecords = notes.ToArray();

            int asad = notes.Count;
            int[] noteCounter = new int[asad];
            int[] arra = allRecords.ToArray();
            //int[] noteCounters = allRecords;
```

Here it is giving me this error:

> Cannot implicity Convert Type WebApplication1.Add.ClassName[] to int []

And that's why I cannot apply this Operand in the below if loop ">="

```
for (int i = 0; i < notes.Count; i++)
{
    if (amount >= notes[i])
    {
        noteCounter[i] = amount / notes[i];
        amount = amount - noteCounter[i] * notes[i];
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the picture of code with BreakPoints]

Comment: what is in column index 1 of the database is not an int.  It may be a null or a string that cannot be converted to an integer.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want an array of `int`, or an array of `ClassName`?

Comment: array of int @TomW

Comment: @jdweng  it is integer in database i have check it is coming from the database

Comment: Are there any null values? The database will allow null for the cell while c# need to explicitly allow nulls using int?

Comment: No there are not null values

Comment: @jdweng I have uploaded the image of the code with the Debugger Please take a look at that

Comment: You are failing the following : ClassName[] allRecords = notes.ToArray();  You are trying to assign an array of integers to a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign the values in the `Col2` property to an int array, you can do so using linq.

```
int[] arra = allRecords.Select(c => c.Col2).ToArray();
```

In your `for` loop, you can do the comparison you are looking for by replacing `amount >= notes[i]` with `amount >= notes[i].Col2`.

I would also suggest renaming the `Col2` property to give it a name that describes what its value actually represents.

Comment: Do you mean `c => c.Col2`? `c->c.Col2` won't compile in C#.

Comment: I edited your question to make the code compile and removed the downvote. Please make sure your code compiles before you post it.